# onmouseover and onmouseleave triggering randomnly on image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, onmouseover, imagemap

I'm having an issue with onmouseover and onmouseleave event. This code only works maybe 5% of the time and I don't understand why. Just looking at the console when I hover over the image map. It triggers the onmouseover then the onmouseleave and then onmouseover again. If I comment out the bootstrap modal show and hide then the image just swaps and triggers events normally. I don't know if this is an issue with bootstrap modals or what but I have two call to action buttons on the same page that trigger normally. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Here is my jquery**

```
  function openAutomation(){
    console.log("openAutomation");
    $('#image-map').attr('src', automation);
    $('#automationModal').modal('show');
  };

  function openIntegration() {
    console.log("openIntegration");
    $('#image-map').attr('src', integration);
    $('#integrationModal').modal('show');
  };


  function closeAutomation(){
    console.log("closeAutomation");
    $('#image-map').attr('src', original);
    $('#automationModal').modal('hide');
  };

  function closeIntegration() {
    console.log("closeIntegration");
    $('#image-map').attr('src', original);
    $('
```

**Here is my HTML Code:**

```
<map name="image-map" class="image-map-class">

<area class="automation-map" onmouseover="openAutomation()" onmouseleave="closeAutomation()" coords="304,559,1011,148,1143,229,1518,447,1516,485,1463,497,1444,510,1436,522,1241,636,1159,716,1076,762,959,801,813,884,494,696,304,589" shape="poly"> 

<area class="integration-map" onmouseover="openIntegration()" onmouseleave="closeIntegration()" coords="1571,477,1456,494,1418,566,1088,756,871,881,868,916,1006,993,1229,1074,1274,1063,1348,1021,1483,944,1629,856,1793,761,1848,732,1881,701,1879,686,1703,551" shape="poly">

</map>
```

Comment: You can also use jquery functions **.mouseover()** and **.mouseleave()**

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately the same results

Answer (score 0):

I would have used an svg image instead of png for that and group elements into interactive areas :

```
<svg viewBox=""><g class="interactive-map">your svg code (path,circle,rect)</g></svg>
```

In this way you will have responsive and interactive areas.

Comment: Please, try to answer less abstract and more close to the context and details of question.

Comment: I'm using a responsive image map js for this works nice responsively. The issue is this was working before without triggering extra events so the issue is not with svg over png. Thanks for the response though man. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Ok managed to get a solution working for this so for anyone using a Bootstap Modal inside an image map with the inner areas using onmouseleave and onmouseover events. Then you need to use the following css:

```
  .modal-backdrop {
    pointer-events: none !important;
 }
  .modal {
    pointer-events: none !important;
  }

  .modal-content{
    pointer-events: none !important;
  }
```

Basically without this it triggers onmouseleave as soon as onmouseover happens and then retriggers onmouseleave again. I really hope this helps someone but I feel like this was very specific for this Website